# FBX seems to be empty when imported into Blender

Tags: import

I'm making a roblox game with a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PlYzgQyco8).

When I export a file as fbx the project exists, but when you open the fbx in blender it just appears as the default...

[image: screenshot after import]

Comment: is your FBX mesh inside the Cube? Check the Outliner top right.

Comment: no it is not inside the cube

Answer (score 5):

You cannot open a .fbx file using Blender.

You must create a new file and import that .fbx file.

In your case, the Blender is opening the default scene instead.

Comment: I wonder why it does not warn the user. There is a message in the console but that is hidden. It also warns that saving in blender will overwrite the .fbx file!

Comment: Yes. There is a warning. I think mrpejo didn't see it.